# OneToMany relationship. How to delete row?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: my database structure]

Hello. I have just learned how to select all related data to, say, the row 
tennismatch.ID = 1:

```
SELECT * FROM tennismatch m
JOIN tennismatch_tennisset ms
ON m.`ID` = ms.`TennisMatch_ID`
JOIN tennisset s
ON ms.`mapOfSets_ID` = s.`ID`
JOIN tennisset_game sg
ON s.`ID` = sg.`TennisSet_ID`
JOIN game g
ON sg.`gamesMap_ID` = g.`ID`
JOIN game_point gp
ON g.`ID` =gp.`Game_ID`
JOIN point p
ON gp.`points_ID` = p.`ID`
 WHERE m.`ID` = 1
```

but I cannot figure how to delete it ALL. 
Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DELETE JOIN statement

```sql
DELETE m, s, g, p, ms, sg, gp
FROM tennismatch m
JOIN tennismatch_tennisset ms ON m.ID = ms.TennisMatch_ID
JOIN tennisset s ON ms.mapOfSets_ID = s.ID
JOIN tennisset_game sg ON s.ID = sg.TennisSet_ID
JOIN game g ON sg.gamesMap_ID = g.ID
JOIN game_point gp ON g.ID = gp.Game_ID
JOIN point p ON gp.points_ID = p.ID
WHERE m.ID = 1
```

Comment: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tennis_scores`.`tennismatch_tennisset`, CONSTRAINT `FK_TENNISMATCH_TENNISSET_TennisMatch_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`TennisMatch_ID`) REFERENCES `tennismatch` (`ID`))

Comment: I can, of cause, disable foreign key checking.